# What is the fastest way to create a select tag with 5000 options in IE6?

Tags: javascript, performance, select, internet-explorer-6

Usability aside: What is the fastest way to create a `select` tag with 5'000 `option` elements in IE6 from JavaScript?

Comment: I wonder if IE6 can even handle that :P

Comment: It can; it will just take its time ....

Comment: How long would it take for someone to find their option out of a list of 5000?

Comment: Please tell me that's for a novelty purpose, 5000 options seems like a UX nightmare.

Comment: @Douglas, Sean M: Which part of "usability aside" didn't you understand? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Short test:

- Collecting a innerHTML-string first    and inject it to the document: around    **300ms**
- appending options to an existing select-element using new Option(): **around 25 sec**

Comment: &%"§$&§%"!! Really? I'd have bet money that DOM manipulation would be much faster then injecting HTML; it certainly is in Firefox.

Comment: Don't have IE6 to test, but in Chrome this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wu6w3/ takes less than 50 ms! :)

Comment: -1 for now (sorry): this is seriously misleading because you're not timing the amount of time taken to add the `<select>` element to the DOM. If you do, you get extremely different results, and the time taken using `new Option()` is nearer 5 times slower than `innerHTML` as opposed to 80 times slower in your example. See the updated example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/YpEhK/5/show/light/

Comment: @Tim Down: first reading, then downvoting: the question is about creating the select, not appending it to the dom. Furthermore the question is about IE6, and there I get the same result with your example(where I don't see any difference onto my example in relation to the given question)

Comment: @Dr. Molle: I did read the question. I think that adding the `<select>` to the DOM is implied: what use is it otherwise? As to my example, I am fully aware the question is about IE 6 and that's precisely what I tested. I fairly consistently get 12.4 seconds for using `new Option()` and 2.4 seconds for `innerHTML`. However, further testing shows that nearly all the time with the `innerHTML` method goes on assembling the HTML string, which could be hugely improved in IE 6 by calling `join("")` on an array containing HTML for each option (see http://fiddle.jshell.net/YpEhK/12/show/light/).

Comment: Conclusion: you're absolutely correct that `innerHTML` is much faster, but I still consider your test flawed. I've made a trivial whitespace edit to your answer to allow me to remove the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Appending options via DOM methods will cause a reflow/repaint of the screen for every option, slowing it all down. Using innerHTML after building a string (in memory) for your select is much faster (as [Dr Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459897/dr-molle) told). An *alternative* to both methods would be to create an in memory [`documentFragment`](http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/xml_dom/objects-documentfragment.html), build your select object in it and finally append it's contents into the exististing DOM.

This aside from the question how a user should handle 5000 options of course (alas, the user isn't programmable ;)

Comment: This doesn't make an awful lot of sense to me. @Dr Molle's example builds the select with all its options before adding it to the DOM, so I don't see how using a `DocumentFragment` would help.

Comment: My hope is that the fragment already does a lot of the parsing, so adding it to the DOM tree could be faster than adding a string that IE needs to parse first.

Comment: @Aaron: That makes no sense. What parsing is the `DocumentFragment` going to do? Just to repeat, creating a `<select>` element using DOM methods is going to be exactly the same whether you then add it to a `<div>` (or some other element) or a `DocumentFragment`. There's no logical reason why a `DocumentFragment` would make the slightest bit of difference.

Comment: @Tim Down: no sweat. The keyword is 'in memory' here, preventing all reflows/repaints that occur when you add to an existing div. Furthermore, use of a documentFragment is presented as *an alternative*. Using a documentFragment one is able to use regular DOM methods to add options (or other elements), which sometimes can be more handy than building a more or less complex string. Programming is just loops and a bunch of ifs right? This is one of them.

Comment: @KooiInc: Maybe I'm missing something. I'm comparing using a `DocumentFragment` to using a `<div>` that *hasn't been added to the DOM yet*, not to the build-a-big-string-and-use-innerHTML approach. If you add your `<select>` to a newly-created div before you add that div to the DOM, there will be no reflows or repaints.

Comment: @Tim Down: you're right, it's possible to use a temporary div (not added to the DOM), append the nodes you want and append or insert the contents of it to some existing element (you'd have to use .firstChild of your div). The documentFragment is *intended* for this kind of use (http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DocumentFragment), that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: I don't know why I even mentioned the div: you could just create the `<select>` element on its own , add the options and then add it to the DOM. I just don't see any need for a `DocumentFragment`, and I do understand what they are and how they can be useful.

Comment: Let's say the *bottom line* is: as long as you are working things out in memory (as opposed to adding elements to the DOM on the go) you're on the faste lane.

Comment: geez `TIm Down` no need to be so defensive