# How to make div stack in css?

Tags: css

How to make div's stack like in the picture?

[image]

Comment: Create dynamic from JS code , you have already lot of Q/A about this subject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index` **AND** `position:absolute;`

For more information go to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

**AND**

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at these position constants? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

You can put them relative to each other to reach something like in your picture.