# Creating dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, solidity

Trying to make a dynamic div but i don't know how. Wrote a solidity smart contract that accepts an array of struct. In the smart contract i can use a get function to display the data inside. Data in the array is treated like a history, it consists of amount (making a crowdfund site), date, currency used, etc. Since the get function in the smart contract can only extract one part of the array, i thought of putting the get function into the while loop and extract the whole history array..

```
<div id=set>
  <a>value1</a>
  <a>value2</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to dynamically create another div with the same amount of < a > in the div. If i had 10 sets of data to display in that div, i wish to create only 10 sets of that div. Can createElement() be used to do that? Couldn't find any solution that works. Totally have no idea on how to create it. Can someone please help.

Would it be rational to extract the data from the array using a while loop and putting it in a div to display or would it use too much gas for this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically creating HTML elements using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why would you want to do this, but you can do like this:

```
$('#set a').each(function(){
  $('#set').after( "<div></div>");
});
```

It selects all of the `<a>...</a>` inside the `<div id="set">...</div>` element, and for each one of those inserts a `<div></div>` element. It inserts the element right next to `#set` but you can change that to any other element you could select.

I'm supplying jQuery code since you tagged the question as jQuery.

Hope it helps,

Comment: i thought of using this because im extracting a struct array from a solidity smart contract. But the only way i know how is to extract it one by one. I can display one set of data. but if say, 3 sets of data, i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of anchor tags by using this function `getElementsByTagName('a').length` from the hosting `div`. Then use that number to create new divs. This solution is done using vanilla JS.

```js
function createDynamicDivs(){
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var noOfAnchors = document.getElementById('set').getElementsByTagName('a').length;
  for(var i=0;i<noOfAnchors;i++){
      var newContent = document.createElement("a");
   newContent.textContent= "Test ";
   newDiv.appendChild(newContent); 
  }
    document.getElementById('new').appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```html
<div id=set>
     <a>value1</a>
     <a>value2</a>
</div>
<div id="new"></div>
<button onclick="createDynamicDivs()">Generate</button>
```