# Javascript / CSS How to make several div elements with different data that are entered into the same input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> How does one create a new div through the input form (using the
>   button) a div appears with the data that was entered last?

I want to create a new div with data from input form.
Next I want to create a new div using the same. But using a new data record only for the first div and another that i created div's doesn't have any data.

How do I go about making that new input = new div+new data from this input&

```
let infoData = {
    budget: 0,
    expenses: 0,
    balance: 0,
    expenseObj: {
        name: "",
        amount: 0
    },
    budgetSubmit: function() {
        infoData.budget = parseInt(document.getElementById('budget-input').value);
        budgetAmount = infoData.budget;
        document.getElementById('budget-amount').innerHTML=budgetAmount;
    },
    expenseSubmit: function() {
        infoData.expenses = parseInt(document.getElementById('expense-input').value);
        expenseName = document.getElementById('expense-name').value;
        infoData.expenseObj.name = expenseName;
        expenseAmount = infoData.expenses;
        infoData.expenseObj.amount = expenseAmount;
        document.getElementById('expense-amount').innerHTML=expenseAmount;
    },
    balanceSubmit: function() {
        infoData.balance = infoData.budget;
        balanceAmount = infoData.balance;
        document.getElementById('balance-amount').innerHTML=balanceAmount;
    } 
}

calcBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    infoData.budgetSubmit();
    infoData.balanceSubmit();
});

addExpBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    infoData.expenseSubmit();
});

addExpBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    balanceAmount = balanceAmount - expenseAmount;
    document.getElementById('balance-amount').innerHTML=balanceAmount;
});

let divEvent = document.getElementById('expense-row');

if (typeof(divEvent) !== "undefined") {
    addExpBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        const divExpense = document.createElement('div');

        divExpense.className = 'div-expense';

        divExpense.innerHTML = `
        <p>
            <b class="text-uppercase">name: </b><span id="div-expense-name">Name</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b class="text-uppercase">amount: </b><span id="div-expense-amount">0</span>₴
        </p>
        <p>
            <span id="div-expense-delete">Delete</span>
        </p>`;

        document.getElementById('expense-row').appendChild(divExpense);
        document.getElementById('div-expense-name').innerHTML=infoData.expenseObj.name;
        document.getElementById('div-expense-amount').innerHTML=infoData.expenseObj.amount;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far and where it is failing. Share your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically creating HTML elements using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, it is not that i mean

Comment: That question's answers show how to create elements. Your question asks how to create elements. [Edit] your question to show how your question differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create the div when you press the button, you could do this:

```
    $("button").click(function(){
      const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      const newDivText = document.createTextNode("");
      $(newDivText).append($("input").val());
      $(newDiv).append(newDivText);
      $(document).append(newDiv);
    });
```

I think that is what you're after. If you need any explanation, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but how to make new div with data that input in form (data=<p id="data-expense-amount></p>

Comment: From what I understand, you want whatever is typed into the input box to appear in the div, right? So in my example, you'll want to change the 'input' in `$(newDivText).append($("input").val())` to whatever the id of your input field is. does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. It's what I want

Answer (score -1):

```js
function addDiv(event){
event.preventDefault();

var input= document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = input.value;
document.body.appendChild(div);
input.value='';



}
```

```html
<form action ="#">
<input type=text/>
<button onclick='addDiv(event)'type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```