# how to access row numbet of input box javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for suggestions on how to get this to work.

```
<input type='text' id='%(settling_cell_id)s' data-row='%(row)s' value='%(val)s' size = '9' style='height:20px' onchange='getvalue(this)'>

getvalue = function(settling_amount_cell){                   
    console.log(settling_amount_cell.value);
    console.log(settling_amount_cell.id);
    console.log(settling_amount_cell.data-row);
}
```

I can access `this.value`, `this.size` and `this.id`, but `this.data-row` or this['data-row'] is undefined.

How can I access `data-row`?

Comment: You should look at this - dynamically-generated elements have to be properly added to the document for them to be visible to JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It's an attribute, specifically a `data-*` attribute. There are two ways to use it in modern browsers:

1. Use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

   ```
   settling_amount_cell.getAttribute("data-row");
   ```
2. Use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset):

   ```
   settling_amount_cell.dataset.row; // or dataset["row"], but not dataset["data-row"]
   ```

Note that `dataset` is newer so it isn't available on obsolete browsers. Also note that `dataset` does some guessing about what the data is supposed to look like and parses it. For instance, if you had only digits in the attribute, the type of the value you got back would be `number` rather than `string`. In contrast, `getAttribute` will always give you the string completely unchanged.