# JavaScript show hidden inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a simple form which has a select to add a number of people, I would like the inputs to appear depending on the number that the user selects.

This is mi HTML

```
<div class="quote-form__item" id="DependentsCount">
    <label class="quote-form__item" for="DependentsCount">
        <select class="quote-form__select" id="DependentsCount" name="extra[health_depents_count]">
            <option value=""># of adults 19 and over</option>
            <?php  if(!empty($data['extra[health_depents_count]'])):  ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data['extra[health_depents_count]'] ?>" selected ><?echo $data['extra[health_depents_count]'] ?></option>
            <?php  endif;  ?>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="4">5</option>
            <option value="4">6</option>
            <option value="4">7</option>
            <option value="4">8</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="page-quote-form__item" id="AdultItem1" style="display:none;">
  <label class="quote-form__item" for="Adult1">
      <input class="quote-form__input only-numbers" id="Adult1" type="tel" name="extra[health_adult_1]" maxlength="2" required placeholder="Age of the 1st adult" aria-label="Age of the 1st adult">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="page-quote-form__item" id="AdultItem2" style="display:none;">
    <label class="quote-form__item" for="Adult2">
        <input class="quote-form__input only-numbers" id="Adult2" type="tel" name="extra[health_adult_2]" maxlength="2" required placeholder="Age of the 2st adult" aria-label="Age of the 2st adult">
    </label>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: So you want to generate `n` number of inputs based off the number given?

Comment: On StackOverflow it is expected that you put forth a bit of effort to try something first. Give something a go. Take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically creating HTML elements using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript)

Comment: Maximum 8 inputs.

Comment: Of course having a limit you could duplicate your code and use `display:none` in order to show/hide elements. But it is a very bad practice. So better think of the problem as you have no limit.

Comment: Another (better) possibility is to use some dynamic framework (as https://vuejs.org for example) which allows you to play with what you want and much more. But it requires learning, so depend on your availability.

Comment: Might you help me? I do not have much knowledge in JS and I am learning

Comment: If you are willing to learn jQuery (recommended), you can try reading this: https://www.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/.  Otherwise, read this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-dynamically-create-new-elements-in-javascript/. The web is full of tutorials.