# How do you use JavaScript to create input fields dynamically in child table using a value entered by user?

Tags: javascript

I need to create fields dynamically in child table using JavaScript based on a value entered by a user.

eg. if the user enters a 5 then 5 fields has to be created. Is it possible?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript

Comment: See my answer below. Based on your question, I believe my code does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

Step 1: Read the value of the input field to determine how many new fields to create.

```js
// parseInt is necessary because DOM input values are string types.
const numberOfFields = parseInt(input.value)
```

Step 2: Dynamically create the new input fields.

```js
for (let i=0; i < numberOfFields; i++) {
  const input = document.createElement('input')
  document.body.appendChild(input)
}
```

Comment: I need to create new fields inside a child table. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

See the working code below.

I've added comments for explanation.

```js
function addInput() {
//get input value
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
  //container for new inputs
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  // if inputVal is greater than 0 append new inputs
  for (i = 0; i < inputVal; i++) {
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    container.appendChild(newInput);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Select number and submit to add more inputs</p>
<input id="inputVal" type="number"></input>
<br/>
<div id="container">

</div>
<br />
<button onclick="addInput();">Add Input</button>
```

Comment: I need to create new fields inside a child table. How to do that?