# Change color of a text in textarea that has been appended

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a code where the user can add new textarea just by clicking on a button. I'm cloning the one div I already have, I've seen this solution on stackoverflow.
Now I want the user to be able to change color of text in textarea. It works fine with the first textarea but not the cloned ones. I've tried to change from "eventListener" to "on." but it didn't work. I'm using selector to choose what color the text should have.

Is there any easy solution to make the other divs change color too? I'm guessing it's something with them not having the event listener

Comment: When you clone, you need to give it a new ID, otherwise they both have the same ID and any `.getElById` / `$("#..)` will only give the first one as IDs must be unique.    How does your "colorChanger" know which one should be changed?  Are they both in the same wrapper?

Comment: How do I give new ID? Can it be done with a loop? Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

If the changeColor function has to change the color of all the elements then creating a new element with a class that is common is enough.

But in case you want to specifically change a particular element's color then you need to give a unique id for the element in order to access the element after creating it.

You can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536711/12774953

Once every element has a unique id then using the id you can change colors.

Comment: If every new div with textarea has unique id then I would also need a new function that changes color, for every new id?  Or am I missing something? I want to be able to choose the color in every new div

Comment: Yes. You have to identify which element is being clicked. Based on that, you can get the particular element's id. That id has to be passed to the function that changes color. That would work for your requirement.

Comment: The question is: do you have a single "color changer" that affects all textareas or is there one for each text area? (multiple colour changer or single)

Comment: I only have one changeColor function. Is there any simple and quick way to do this? So that I can be able to change the text color in every new div that the user creates/clones.

Comment: Remove the `id=T` and give it a class and then get by class name to get all of them